# Return 0 if no match found from array with MySQL IN statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I know there are many similar questions and answers, but none of them are working in this case, as I'm using `IN` statement to get matches from array and my dates are in `varchar` data type because of its format. Here it is:

I'm trying to check if array items exists in database and get the count for each of them as an array. My SQL query runs fine and gets the results, but the only problem is that I want it to return 0 for array items that does not exist in a database instead of skipping it.

So for example here is my database table:

```
postId   reactedTo   reactedDate
126      Like        22 Jun 2019
172      Haha        24 Jun 2019
172      Wow         27 Jun 2019
132      Like        27 Jun 2019
```

Here is my function to run the SQL Query and get the results as an array

```
public function reactionsAnalytics() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tableName = $wpdb->prefix.'reactions';
    $dates = $this->getLastNDays(7); //array('22 Jun 2019', '23 Jun 2019', ... ,'28 Jun 2019');
    $reacts = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT reactedDate, count(*) AS count
  FROM {$tableName} 
 WHERE reactedDate IN ('".implode("','", $dates)."')  
 GROUP 
    BY reactedDate
", ARRAY_A);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($reacts as $react) {
        $result[] = $react['count'];        
    }

    wp_die(json_encode($result));
}
```

The expected outout of this function is ["1","0","1","0","0","2","0"], but I'm getting ["1","1","2"]. How can I prevent the $reacts query from skipping not found items and make it output 0 instead?

I've tried using `COALESCE`, `IFNULL` and `SUM` in various variations but got same results without zeroes.

Here is the SQL Fiddle and you can play with it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffbb98/5

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the _exact_ output you expect from this sample data.  Note that 4 records generally cannot generate 6 values with the query you showed us.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to show zeroes for no matches from given array. So counts for matches and zeroes for no matches. Expected output is `["1","0","1","0","0","2","0"]` - array of counts for each date. Output now is `["1","1","2"]` - array of counts only for matched dates.

Comment: `for each date` ... I only see three dates in your sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my sample data is `$dates` variable, which is the array of last week dates in given format. I want to compare it with my `reactedDate` column and get count for matching dates, and 0 for non-matches. Currently I get count for matching dates as it returns `["1","1","2"]` which is count for 22, 24 and 27 Jun. I want it not to skip non-matching days and return 0 for them, so output should be `["1","0","1","0","0","2","0"]` and zeroes will be for 23, 25, 26, 28 Jun

Comment: use count with case and when then I think you will get your expected answer.

Comment: hope this will work

SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(Names) AS COUNT_OF_N,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(Names) <= 3
             THEN COUNT(Names) * 2
         WHEN COUNT(Names) <= 6
             THEN COUNT(Names) * 3 
    END AS Multiplied
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    Names

Comment: @BhaveshTailor I can't figure it out how to use them in this case. Can you give me a sample SQL query?

Comment: try this I am not sure please check and let me know or it's better u create sqlfiddel 
"SELECT reactedDate, count(*) AS count,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 0 
             THEN '0'
         WHEN COUNT(Names) > 1
             THEN COUNT(*)
    END AS Multiplied FROM {$tableName} WHERE reactedDate IN ('".implode("','", $dates)."') GROUP BY reactedDate"

Comment: @BhaveshTailor Unfortunately both of this queries results in error. Here is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iXBsGe5cA5PzyC9ZT3KpKy/0

Comment: @AkakiKhujadze try with two tables you can store checking dates in one table and compare with your another module if it is null it will return NULL value

Comment: @AkakiKhujadze if we get null in different column and not null then it's ok?

Comment: @BhaveshTailor I don't get it. We need zeroes for non-matching dates.

Comment: @Thayifkabir So I have to create another table with `$dates` array? In fact `$dates` array is dynamic, so it represents dates of last 7 days. Tomorrow dates will be different in this array.

Comment: Just parse the result in your application code, comparing it to the original array.

Comment: @Strawberry result is not returning anything for non-matching items to compare. That's the problem.

Comment: @AkakiKhujadze Yep, a failed match is a zero.

Comment: You can't detect a failed match, it skips it.

Comment: @AkakiKhujadze get only dates from query and use loop to compare with $dates array if same found add count or else set count to zero

Comment: @Thayifkabir Accepted answer author did nearly the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to complicate the query, you simply need to change your application (PHP) code slightly. Get the query results for the dates available in the DB. Now, in PHP code, simply check if the count is available for the date or not. If yes, use the count, else set as zero.

```
// Change the SQL query result to an array with date as key, and count as value
$reacts_mod = array_combine(array_column($reacts, 'reactedDate'), 
                            array_column($reacts, 'count'));

// Now prepare the $result
$result = array();
// Loop over input dates here
foreach ($dates as $dt) {

    // If you have count obtained from the query result, then consider that else 0
    if ( isset($reacts_mod[$dt]) ) {
        $result[] = $reacts_mod[$dt];
    } else {
        $result[] = 0;
    }

    // Note: PHP7 code would be simply:
    // $result[] = $reacts_mod[$dt] ?? 0;
}
```

Comment: That is working! Thank you for your answer. converting query results in PHP array and checking if got results did the trick.